# Closed form of :$ (n+1)^4y_{n+1}-n^4y_{n}=2n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I want to compute limit of $y_n$  for $  (n+1)^4y_{n+1}-n^4y_{n}=2n+1$ but i have  accrossed a problem to get it's closed form i know only that the intial condition could be deduced by taking $n=0$ to get $y_{1}=1$, then my question is how i can get Closed form of :$  (n+1)^4y_{n+1}-n^4y_{n}=2n+1$ for the computation of limit ?

Comment: You do not need a closed form to find the limit.

Comment: I want y(n) defined by n

Comment: Use that $$y_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{C}{n^4}$$

Comment: Hint: 1) if $a_{n+1} - a_n = b_{n+1} - b_n$, then $a_{n} - b_{n}$ is independent of $n$. 2) $2n+1 = (n+1)^2 - n^2$

Comment: Just compute a couple of values and guess the the limit -- it's easy.

Comment: @achillehui, could you show me some detaill how i can get it , by providing at a least a short answer and thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Just sum the equations $(n+1)^4y_{n+1}-n^4y_{n}=2n+1$ for $n=1,\dots, N-1$. There's lot of cancellation on the LHS and a familiar sum on the RHS.

> Indeed, we get $N^4y_{N}-y_{1}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(2n+1)=N^2-1$

Comment: @ihf , could you add some detaill for summation because i want to compute it's limit by this way i can't continue because really i'm not familiar with that

Comment: by this way y(n)= 1/n² and the limit is 0

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$(n+1)^4y_{n+1}-n^4y_{n}=2n+1$$ define $z_n=n^4 y_n$ to get 
$$z_{n+1}-z_n=2n+1\implies z_n=n^2+C\implies y_n=\frac{n^2+C}{n^4}$$